# A variable seems to be uninitialized

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am calling a stored procedure from PHP and it is supposed to give me a date.

```
global $dbh;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL date_sp(?)");
$stmt->bindParam($employee_id, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
// Call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();
```

I keep getting an error that variable `$return_value` (in the third line) is not initialized.

Comment: Are all those variables initialized?

Comment: Which variable is it saying is not initialized?

Comment: $return_value variable

Comment: Please give proper coding example it's not proper as per me.

Comment: bindParam isn't being used correctly in this case. $employee_id should be 1 unless you're running through a loop. $return_value is the value that you are binding in place of  the `?`. You retrieve the result as `$result = $stmt->fetch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need a named placed holder. Using the ? you would just do the following.

```
global $dbh;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL date_sp(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $employee_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 
// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();
```

To actually fetch the result you would do something like:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch()
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful here. [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) is used *only* for input parameters. Return values are handled with a different method. You should be doing:

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL date_sp(:employee_id)");
    $stmt->bindParam('employee_id', $employee_id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 
    // call the stored procedure
    $stmt->execute();
```

Whenever writing code of this sort, be sure to check the API reference very carefully. There's often some subtle things you have to get perfectly right or nothing will work.

If you want to bind result values you can use [`bindColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php) but it's often easier to just fetch it as an array and deal with it directly.

Comment: can you please show me how to get the result in the variable $return_value?

Comment: The `bindColumn` link in my answer explains.

Comment: I am quite a beginner in PHP :), so I have this stored procedure that actually just executes a query and gets a result at the end. The result is just a single value, please show me how to properly use the bindcolumn method and return this single value

Comment: I understand you're a beginner, and that's fine, but it's also important to visit the documentation so you know what tools you have available and how they work. The comments section includes a variety of examples that might more closely resemble what you're trying to do. If you're really stumped, make an attempt and open a new question with how far you got.